# How To Draw Standard Primitives With Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

Does Vulkan provide functionality to draw basic primitives? Point, Line, Rectangle, Filled Rectangle, Rounded Corner Rectangle, Filled Rounded Corner Rectangle, Circle, Filled Circle, etc.. ?

I don't believe there are any VkCmdDraw* commands that provide this functionality. If that is true, what needs to be done to draw simple primitives like this?

Comment: Just about ~2000 lines of code, a couple of shader programs, a shader compiler, and 1 week of your life. ;)

Comment: It should be noted that learning Vulkan is a good idea because of how powerful it is, the freedom and potential performance advantage. That said, @alexpanter's statement is correct, although a bit hyperbolic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vulkan is not vector graphics library. It is an API for your GPU.

It does have (square) Points and Lines though. But size other than 1 is optional. And any other high-level features you can think of are not part of the API, except those in `VK_EXT_line_rasterization` extension.

Rectangle can be a Line Strip of four lines.

Filled Rectangle is probably two filled triangles (resp. Triangle Strip primitive).

Rounded corners and Circles probably could be made by rendering the bounding rectangle, and discarding the unwanted parts of the shape in the Fragment Shader. Or something can be done with a Stencil Buffer. Or there is a Compute Shader, which can do anything. Alternatively they can be emulated with triangles.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. Primitives are created by specifying however many vertices are required to make the shape of whatever primitive is in question. I assume I'll need a few different pipelines depending on if I'm making a point/line/rect/filled-rect? When dealing with rounded corners, could this essentially be a normal rect/filled-rect and the shader could deal with making the edges rounded?

Comment: @KKlouzal, yea it should work in the fragment shader to `if( ... ) discard;` the parts of the pixels in the rectangle that are the rounded edge.

Comment: I also stumbled upon the `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures::fillModeNonSolid` data field. Some documentation text: "fillModeNonSolid specifies whether point and wireframe fill modes are supported. If this feature is not enabled, the VK_POLYGON_MODE_POINT and VK_POLYGON_MODE_LINE enum values must not be used.".

Answer (score 4):

There are no such utility functions in Vulkan. If you need to draw a certain primitive you need to provide vertices (and indices) yourself. So if you e.g. want to draw a circle you need to calculate the vertices using standard trigonometric functions, and provide them for your draw calls using a buffer.

This means creating a buffer via `vkCreateBuffer`, allocating the memory required to store your data into that buffer via `vkAllocateMemory` and after mapping that buffer into host memory you can copy your primitive's vertices (and/or indices) to such a buffer.

If you're on a nun-unified memory architecture (i.e. desktop GPUs) you also want to upload that data from host to the device for best performance then.

Once you've got a buffer setup, backed by memory and your values stored in that buffer you can draw your primitive using `vkCmdDraw*`commands.

Comment: Yes, I'm already in a position where I have command buffers drawing things. I was looking for an approach to use when drawing a variety of basic shapes.

Answer (score 2):

All available types of primitives are defined in the standard, and can be set through the [VkPrimitiveTopology](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkPrimitiveTopology.html) member `topology` in VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.
The manual page of VkPrimitiveTopology states the following possible values:

```
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST = 0,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_LIST = 1,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_STRIP = 2,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST = 3,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_STRIP = 4,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_FAN = 5,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_LIST_WITH_ADJACENCY = 6,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_STRIP_WITH_ADJACENCY = 7,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST_WITH_ADJACENCY = 8,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_STRIP_WITH_ADJACENCY = 9,
VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_PATCH_LIST = 10,
```

You may also need to change `polygonMode`, if you're rendering a shape you don't want filled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is any good help, but I have used geometry shaders with OpenGL to draw circles and ellipses. This works by adding a uniform value stating the amount of subdivision and the radius, and then generate a bunch of triangles or a bunch of lines (depending on whether it should be filled or "wireframe". This required a little trigonometry (sin and cos). For filled circles I would use triangle-fan primitive, and for wireframe circles I would use line-loop. For Vulkan: whichever primitive is available, as @theRPGMaster suggested.

I hear many places that geometry shaders are very slow to use, comparably, so that should probably not be your go-to choice, as I assume you picked Vulkan for performance reasons. On thing that geometry shaders could be good for, is the rectangular selection box you see in e.g. Windows Explorer when holding down left mouse button and moving the cursor. At least I found that to work well.

From what I have seen of Vulkan so far it seems even more barebones than OpenGL is, so I would expect nothing in terms of supporting this kind of thing.